# Tracking in photoshop vs LBearing and RBearing

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, font-forge

I wish to modify the spacing in a font such that it matches the look in photoshop.
In photoshop I have set the *"tracking"* to be 200.
In FontForge (fonteditor), I can only modify LBearing and Rbearing. 
Does 200 trackin in photoshop mean 100 LBeargin and 100 Rbearing in FontForge?
Or is it 200 LB and 200 RB?

Comment: Hi Vlad. Maybe a silly question but.. What's wrong with using tracking?

Comment: Also have you actually tried it? Seems your question is whether to use 100 or 200 bearing each side, doesn't seem like it would take much to just try both?

Comment: tracking is not available as a property in FontForge. I wanted to understand what is the relationship between photoshop tracking and bearings in general.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. As far as I'm aware tracking is always something that is done after the fact and not a property of the font so although you can probably get the same spacing by adjusting the bearings on the actual font, you probably can't translate the values 1:1 and it will probably need a bit of trial and error. I'm by no means certain though.

Comment: My previous point stands though, have you tried? Seems like a sure fire way to find out the answer.